# jQuery mobile's loadpage() inserts an empty container

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having an issue with the jQuery mobile's loadPage() method. I am using the method to load a popup container. When the page gets loaded, the #popup DIV is empty (no .header, .content, or .footer DIVs) when I inspect it. Am I doing something wrong?

**HTML (popup.php)**

```
<div id="popup" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a">
    <div class="header" data-role="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content" data-role="content" data-iscroll>
        Something.
    </div>
    <div class="footer" data-role="footer">
        <a class="close" href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '.find-page', function() {
    // load popup once
    if (!$('#popup').length) {
        $.mobile.loadPage('popup.php', { changeHash: false });
    }
});
```

Comment: popup or a dialog? You want to show it or just load it?

Comment: I want to load a popup.